# How to move 2 Scrollbars Simultaneously using Python Dash Ploty

Tags: python, plotly-dash

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, ctx
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

app = Dash(__name__)

data = OrderedDict(
\[
("Date", \["2015-01-01", "2015-10-24", "2016-05-10", "2017-01-10", "2018-05-10", "2018-08-15"\]),
("Region", \["Montreal", "Toronto", "New York City", "Miami", "San Francisco", "London"\]),
("Temperature", \[1, -20, 3.512, 4, 10423, -441.2\]),
("Humidity", \[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60\]),
("Pressure", \[2, 10924, 3912, -10, 3591.2, 15\]),
\]
)

df = pd.DataFrame(
OrderedDict(\[(name, col_data \* 10) for (name, col_data) in data.items()\])
)

app.layout = html.Div(children= \[dash_table.DataTable(
data=df.to_dict('records'),
columns=\[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns\],
page_action='none',
style_table={'height': '300px', 'overflowY': 'auto'}
),
html.Br(),
dash_table.DataTable(
data=df.to_dict('records'),
columns=\[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns\],
page_action='none',
style_table={'height': '300px', 'overflowY': 'auto'}
)\])

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This is the sample Code for displaying 2 tables in the web using Python Dash, How can I connect 2 scrollbars i.e movement of one scroll bar should make movement of another scroll bar.

Thank you!